# In FMDB,insertion is done in uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
TitleArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@“aaaa",@“bbbb",@“cccc",@“dddd",@“eeee",@“ffff", nil];

   DescArray=[NSMutuableArray arrayWithObjects:@“xxx”,@“yyy”,@“zzz”,@“www”,@“sss”,@“ppp”,nil];

Array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

FMDatabase *Database=[FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Utility getDatabasePath]];

[Database open];
[Database executeUpdate:@"insert into table(title,description) values(?,?);",TitleArray,DescArray];

FMResultSet *Results=[Database executeQuery:@"select *from table"];

while ([Results next]) {

     Obj *Object1=[[Obj alloc]init];

   Object1.Title=[Results stringForColumn:@"title"];

   Object1.Description=[Results stringForColumn:@"description"];
    [Array addObject:Object];
}

[Database close];
```

Comment: Try reading the log before posting it on Stackoverflow. What does `DB Error: 1 "no such table: newstable"` tell you?

Comment: Your database has no table named `newstable`. Why is that? Only you can tell. Check your table creation queries.

Comment: Checked the table creation but not working

Comment: Because it is still not creating the table. Add your code for creation of the table named `newstable`

Comment: can you add your query to your question. looks like your table doesn't exist or you have spelt it wrong. Provide more code please.

Comment: @Preetha `[Database executeUpdate:@"insert into table(title,description) values(?,?);",TitleArray,DescArray];` ? what is table here? give table name here.

Comment: newstable only this is..

Comment: Also why are you giving arrays to value which should take only string? You will have to run a loop of insertion query. See my updated answer. And it is not the code for table creation. You should read tutorials on iOS development practices and Database usage first.

Comment: i have to insert the values in tableview so that only am using arrays

Comment: That does not mean you should try to insert array into tables. Anyways, SO is not a place to teach you basics of iOS development. Try to understand the pointers I gave you and you will find your problem (God knows there are many) and fix them.

Answer (score 3):

1>Please check if you have a table named newstable in your database or 
2>you are not connected to the right schema.

please provide more information so that we can help.
at least show your database and the connections you made.

TRY this to create table first
(random table with random columns)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  account ;
CREATE TABLE  account ( 
                     +"accountNum INT( 11 ),"
                   +"accountName TEXT,"
                    +"description TEXT,"
                     +"statusAccount TEXT,"
                    ) ;
```

Comment: [Database executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE if not exists tablename(title text,description text,date Date)"];

Comment: this is the  query am used to create the table

Comment: @Preetha there is no primary key in your table. Also Are you sure you opened the database before executing that query?

Comment: am not understanding clearlr sorry..can you please explain me

Comment: first make sure that you are able to create table , after you are sure that your table is created, then try inserting values in it . maybe you are having trouble creating the table

Comment: This query will delete the table account whenever it runs with all the data in account thus effectively destroying the app. `Create table if not exists` is the way to go here. Also edit your code snippet to suit the OP's requirements. OP's table is named newstable and has description,title and date in it. @Bawa

Comment: what if she's not even making the table ,

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have any such table in your database as the error log tells you. Check your database queries. As your schema contains title, description and date stamp, Table Creation Query for your `newstable` table should be like:

```
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"Your database path"];
[database open];
[database executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE newstable (id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NULL,title TEXT DEFAULT NULL,description TEXT DEFAULT NULL,date TEXT DEFAULT NULL)"];
[database close];
```

In your code, your insertion Query is wrong as you are saying `insert into table` instead of giving table name. You are also passing arrays as values when instead you should be passing strings. It should be:

```
//Assuming your desc Array and title Array will be of the same count. 
for(int i=0;i<titleArray.count;i++)
{
     [database executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO newstable (title, description) VALUES (?, ?)", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [titleArray objectAtIndex:i]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [descArray objectAtIndex:i]], nil];
}
```

Similarly `FMResultSet *Results=[Database executeQuery:@"select *from table"];` should be:

```
FMResultSet *Results=[Database executeQuery:@"select *from newstable"];
```

You should follow proper naming convention for your variables too.

Personally I prefer to create a `.db` file using some external program, add it to my App bundle and then import it to my App's document directory on first run. Visual creation always saves a lot of trouble in case you misspell something.

Comment: Mr.NSNoob am tried but that is not  woked,stil showing the same error

Comment: @Preetha You need to open your database before creating the table using `[database open]` method. This query which I wrote here works alright. Can't say why isn't it working for you unless you show your code in your question.

Comment: Add your complete Database initialization method to your question body @Preetha

Comment: Inserting the data in this way..load the data in uitableview